# Passive voice misuse for my sentence

Tags: sentence, passive-voice

> I will be remembered as an individual who was kind, compassionate and
>   always helped others.

I checked my sentence on grammarly and it pointed out that this sentence has "passive voice misuse". Can someone please help me fix the error? I am not sure what the error is.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your passive. I only don't like the unbalanced predicate of the relative clause, where you have "kind" and "compassionate" separated by a comma and linked with "was" and then an action verb. I prefer: *I will be remembered as an individual who was kind, compassionate and helpful.* OR *I will be remembered as an individual who behaved kindly, showed compassion and helped others.* Can you see how the unbalance has been fixed?

Comment: @Gustavson thanks, I could feel the "incorrectness" of my sentence but didn't know how to fix it. Thank you so much !

Comment: @Gustavson Yes. See the piece I ADDED to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammarly is misparsing *was...helped* as a passive. The actual error is a subtle matter of punctuation. You have listed your three characteristics as

> ... was kind, compassionate, and always helped others.

This construction leads a literal-minded "reader" like Grammarly to believe the three characteristics have the same syntactic role, but this is not the case: the first two, *kind* and *compassionate* are adjective complements of *was*, while *helped* is not an adjective but a new verb, unconnected with *was*.

You can eliminate this reading by saying:

```
                        kind
                   was  and
                        compassionate
 ... someone who   and
                   always helped others ...
```

That is,

> ... someone who was kind and compassionate and always helped others.

ADDED:
Gustavson's alternative phrasings, which preserve the list construction at the cost of changing the words employed, are arguably better if the new words preserve your meaning.